# ASP.NET MVC Model Id

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, and I'm having some problems with a little learning project.
I set up a project and a database, and now I want to print my products out into my view. But I'm lost as to how I make the page only look for specific Category Ids

I have my Categories printed out like this :

```
@model List<SoftgunZone.Models.Category>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

<p>

</p>

<h2>Produkter</h2>

@foreach (var category in Model)
{
<div class="categorylist">

    <p>@category.Name</p>

    <img src=@category.Image height="280" width="210" />
</div>

}
```

Each product has it's own Category Id number and when I click on the category it is supposed to take me to a page where it shows all the products under that category id
.How do I print my products with the same category id out on a page each?

Comment: You need a link that passes the ID of the category to a controller method that gets the products based that ID and then return a view of those products.

Comment: `product` tag is not suitable for this type of question..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would isolate the correct categories when loading the data... so in the view you would perform the same type of isolation using linq.

```
@model List<SoftgunZone.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
    ViewBag.CategoryId = 1;
}
<p></p>

<h2>Produkter</h2>

@foreach (var category in Model.Where(c => c.Id.Equals(ViewBag.CategoryId)).ToList())
{
<div class="categorylist">

    <p>@category.Name</p>

    <img src=@category.Image height="280" width="210" />
</div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Where(x =>x.Id).toList())
{
<div class="categorylist">

    <p>@category.Name</p>

    <img src=@category.Image height="280" width="210" />
</div>

}
```